# $ \lim _{n\to \infty }\left(\sqrt{n+\sqrt{n}}+\sqrt{n-\sqrt{n}}\right) = \lim _{n\to \infty } 2 \sqrt{n}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I was wondering if we could do one step more in this equality. I understand that the square roots inside the square roots can be neglected, but I have to explain it and I would prefer to use a "rule" of the limits (like dividing by the highest power of $n$, when we have a fraction for example). Thanks!

Comment: The two limits are both $\infty$, but presumably you want to show that they are closer than that in some sense.

Comment: Yes sorry, they are part of a bigger calculation and that's the simplification done to solve the exercice

Comment: Yes I know, I think this problem is of the same sort as: how do you explain to someone $\lim_{n \to \infty} n^2-n = \lim_{n \to \infty} n^2$. In this case I would say something like: "You can neglect the $n$ because $n^2$ grows faster." I don't want just to give the answer. But I cannot say exactly the same in this case (or maybe I can but it's not that visible), so I was wondering if it is possible to do one step more.

Comment: Maybe what you want to say is that $ \lim \sqrt{ n + \sqrt{n} } + \sqrt{ n - \sqrt{ n} } - 2 \sqrt{n}  = 0 $?

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? \begin{eqnarray}\mathcal L &=&\lim_{n\to \infty} \sqrt{n+\sqrt n}+\sqrt{n-\sqrt n}=\\&=&\lim_{n\to \infty}\sqrt{n}\underbrace{\left(\sqrt{1+\frac1{\sqrt{n}}}+\sqrt{1-\frac1{\sqrt{n}}}\right)}_{\to 2}\end{eqnarray}

Comment: Yes, thanks a lot, I didn't think of doing that...

Comment: In the term of the limit we can put it as $\lim\frac{n^2+n}{n^2}=1$.
In our case $\lim _{n\to \infty }\frac{\sqrt{n+\sqrt{n}}+\sqrt{n-\sqrt{n}}}{\sqrt n}=2$.
Or we can use the asymptotics approach.
$$\sqrt{n+\sqrt{n}}+\sqrt{n-\sqrt{n}}=\sqrt n\Big(\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{\sqrt n}}+\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{\sqrt n}}\Big)$$
$$=\sqrt n\Big(1+\frac{1}{2\sqrt n}-\frac{1}{8n}+1-\frac{1}{2\sqrt n}-\frac{1}{8n}+O\big(\frac{1}{(\sqrt n)^3}\big)\Big)=2\sqrt n+1+O\Big(\frac{1}{n}\Big)$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any fixed $a \in \mathbb{R}$,
\begin{align}
(n + an^{1/2})^{1/2} &= (n(1 + an^{-1/2}))^{1/2} \\
&= n^{1/2}(1 + an^{-1/2})^{1/2} \\
&= n^{1/2}(1 + \frac{1}{2}an^{-1/2}+O(n^{-1})) \\
&= n^{1/2} + \frac{1}{2}a + O(n^{-1/2}).
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

If you use Taylor series

$$\sqrt{n+\sqrt{n}}+\sqrt{n-\sqrt{n}}=2\sqrt n \Big[1-\frac{1}{8 n}-\frac{5}{128 n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right) \Big]$$